# Discord Pypresence crashing custom application after pressing connect button

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, discord, discord.py

This is how the application looks like: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUaix.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYWdS.png

The second [2] image shows how the application should look after pressing the "Connect" button. However, after pressing the button it looks the same (image [1]), although the Discord rich presence starts running.

```
        def rpcstart():

        os.system('start-rpc-script.py')
        
        global rpc_on
        if rpc_on:
            connectbutton.config(image=rpcconnectedimage, state='disabled')
            disconnectbutton.config(image=rpcdisconnectimage, state='normal')
        else:
            connectbutton.config(image=rpcconnectimage)
        menubar.entryconfig(1,label="Status: Connected")
```

This is the part of my script that starts the Discord rich presence. There are no errors or anything similar. It just makes the application unresponsive. Is there any fix for that? Here's the pypresence script that I use:

```
from pypresence import Presence 
import time

start = int(time.time())
client_id = "XXXXXX"
RPC = Presence(client_id)
RPC.connect()

while True:
    RPC.update(
        details = "▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬",
        state = "DEMO.",
        large_image = "logo_rpc_v2",
        large_text = "demo.exe is running!",
        small_image = "green_circle_rpc_v2",
        small_text = "Online",
        start = start,
        buttons = [{"label": "example.net ", "url": "https://example.net/"}, 
{"label": "example.net", "url": "https://example.net"}]
    )
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a `tkinter` question

Comment: The GUI is made with Tkinter.

Comment: Then there is a distinct possibility that running your RPC code in a separate thread will prevent the app from hanging. Any long-running / blocking process that's run in the same thread as tkinter will cause the UI to become unresponsive.

Comment: How would I do that? I plan to merge both codes into one .exe when its done.

Comment: see below for info

Answer (score 0):

Try running your RPC code in a separate thread

```
from threading import Thread


def _rpc_connect(client_id):  # this will be your 'target' function, run in its own thread
    start = int(time.time())
    RPC = Presence(client_id)
    RPC.connect()

    while True:
        RPC.update(
            details = "▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬▬",
            state = "DEMO.",
            large_image = "logo_rpc_v2",
            large_text = "demo.exe is running!",
            small_image = "green_circle_rpc_v2",
            small_text = "Online",
            start = start,
            buttons = [
                {"label": "example.net ", "url": "https://example.net/"}, 
                {"label": "example.net", "url": "https://example.net"}
            ],
        )
        time.sleep(60)


def run_rpc(client_id)
    t_rpc = Threading(
        target=_rpc_connect,
        args=(client_id,),
        daemon=True,
    )
    t_rpc.start()  # start the thread
```

To run the RPC thread, call the `run_rpc` function as usual

```
run_rpc(client_id='XXXXXX')
```

Comment: It occurs to me that the update loop in `_rpc_connect` won't behave as expected...will try to fix later! The gist of running a function in a separate thread still stands however. Apologies!

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new to this and don't really understand how to use this and connect it with my application. I'm using os.system("start-rpc-script.py") to run the rpc code from the custom application. If I put the code from above into vscode, add my id and try to run it, nothing happens. (The rpc code and the application code are in two separate .py files)